# How can I speed up spatial operations in `dplyr::mutate()`?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, r-sf

I am working on a spatial problem using the `sf` package in conjunction with `dplyr` and `purrr`.

I would prefer to perform spatial operations inside a `mutate` call, like so:

```r
simple_feature %>%
  mutate(geometry_area = map_dbl(geometry, ~ as.double(st_area(.x))))
```

I like that this approach allows me to run a series of spatial operations using `%>%` and `mutate`.

I *dislike* that this approach seems to significantly increase the run-time of the `sf` functions (sometimes prohibitively) and I would appreciate hearing suggestions about how to overcome this speed loss.

Here is a reprex that illustrates the speed loss problem in detail.

---

> **Please note:** this is not a *minimal* example and requires downloading a few packages and one file from an ESRI REST API. I hope
>   you'll be kind with me ;)

The objective in this example is to add a new column indicating whether each North Carolina county (`nc`) intersects with any of the waterbodies polygons (`nc_wtr`), as shown in the image below:

[image]

I created a function that performs this calculation: `st_intersects_any()`

Then I benchmark that function on two datasets (`nc` and `nc_1e4`), first using `st_intersects_any()` by itself and then using it inside a `mutate` call.

```r
## |TEST               |  ELAPSED|
## |:------------------|--------:|
## |bm_sf_small        |     0.01|
## |bm_sf_dplyr_small  |     1.22|
## |bm_sf_large        |     0.95|
## |bm_sf_dplyr_large  |   122.88|
```

The benchmarks clearly show that the `dplyr` approach is substantially slower, and I'm hoping that someone has a suggestion for reducing or eliminating this speed loss while still using the `dplyr` approach.

If there are significantly faster ways to do this using `data.table` or some other method that I should check out please let me know about those as well.

Thanks!

#### Reprex

```r
# Setup ----

library(lwgeom) # devtools::install_github('r-spatial/lwgeom) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(sf) 
library(esri2sf) # devtools::install_github('yonghah/esri2sf')
library(rbenchmark) 
library(knitr)

# Create the new sf function: st_intersects_any ----

st_intersects_any <- function(x, y) {
  st_intersects(x, y) %>%
    map_lgl(~ length(.x) > 0)
}

# Load data ----
# NC counties

nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>%
  st_transform(32119)

nc_1e4 <- list(nc) %>%
  rep(times = 1e2) %>%
  reduce(rbind)

# NC watersheds

url <- "https://services.nconemap.gov/secure/rest/services/NC1Map_Watersheds/MapServer/2"

nc_wtr <- esri2sf(url)
## Warning: package 'httr' was built under R version 3.4.2
## 
## Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
## The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
## 
##     flatten
## [1] "Feature Layer"
## [1] "esriGeometryPolygon"

nc_wtr <- st_transform(nc_wtr, 32119) %>%
  st_simplify(dTolerance = 100) # simplify the waterbodies geometries

# plot the data

par(mar = rep(.1, 4))
plot(st_geometry(nc), lwd = 1)
plot(st_geometry(nc_wtr), col = alpha("blue", .3), lwd = 1.5, add = TRUE)

# Benchmark the two approaches

cols <- c("elapsed", "relative")

bm_sf_small <- benchmark({
  st_intersects_any(nc, nc_wtr)
}, columns = cols, replications = 1)

bm_sf_dplyr_small <- benchmark({
  nc %>% transmute(INT = map_lgl(geometry, st_intersects_any, y = nc_wtr))
}, columns = cols, replications = 1)
## Warning: package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.4.2

bm_sf_large <- benchmark({
  st_intersects_any(nc_1e4, nc_wtr)
}, columns = cols, replications = 1)

bm_sf_dplyr_large <- benchmark({
  nc_1e4 %>% transmute(INT = map_lgl(geometry, st_intersects_any, y = nc_wtr))
}, columns = cols, replications = 1)

tests <- list(bm_sf_small, bm_sf_dplyr_small, bm_sf_large, bm_sf_dplyr_large)

tbl <- tibble(
  TEST = c("bm_sf_small", "bm_sf_dplyr_small", "bm_sf_large", "bm_sf_dplyr_large"),
  ELAPSED = map_dbl(tests, "elapsed")
)

kable(tbl,format = "markdown", padding = 2)

## |TEST               |  ELAPSED|
## |:------------------|--------:|
## |bm_sf_small        |     0.01|
## |bm_sf_dplyr_small  |     1.22|
## |bm_sf_large        |     0.95|
## |bm_sf_dplyr_large  |   122.88|





devtools::session_info()
## Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
##  setting  value                       
##  version  R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
##  system   x86_64, mingw32             
##  ui       RTerm                       
##  language (EN)                        
##  collate  English_United States.1252  
##  tz       America/Los_Angeles         
##  date     2018-01-31
## Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
##  package    * version     date       source                            
##  assertthat   0.2.0       2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  backports    1.1.0       2017-05-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  base       * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  bindr        0.1         2016-11-13 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  bindrcpp   * 0.2         2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  broom        0.4.3       2017-11-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  cellranger   1.1.0       2016-07-27 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  class        7.3-14      2015-08-30 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  classInt     0.1-24      2017-04-16 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  cli          1.0.0       2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  colorspace   1.3-2       2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  compiler     3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  crayon       1.3.4       2017-10-30 Github (r-lib/crayon@b5221ab)     
##  curl         3.0         2017-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  datasets   * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  DBI          0.7         2017-06-18 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  devtools     1.13.2      2017-06-02 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  digest       0.6.13      2017-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  dplyr      * 0.7.4       2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  e1071        1.6-8       2017-02-02 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  esri2sf    * 0.1.0       2017-12-12 Github (yonghah/esri2sf@81d211f)  
##  evaluate     0.10.1      2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  forcats    * 0.2.0       2017-01-23 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  foreign      0.8-67      2016-09-13 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  ggplot2    * 2.2.1.9000  2017-12-02 Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@7b5c185)
##  glue         1.2.0.9000  2018-01-13 Github (tidyverse/glue@1592ee1)   
##  graphics   * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  grDevices  * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  grid         3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  gtable       0.2.0       2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  haven        1.1.0       2017-07-09 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  hms          0.4.0       2017-11-23 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  htmltools    0.3.6       2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  httr       * 1.3.1       2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  jsonlite   * 1.5         2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  knitr        1.18        2017-12-27 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  lattice      0.20-35     2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  lazyeval     0.2.1       2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  lubridate    1.7.1       2017-11-03 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  lwgeom     * 0.1-1       2017-12-16 Github (r-spatial/lwgeom@baf22c6) 
##  magrittr     1.5         2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  memoise      1.1.0       2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  methods    * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  mnormt       1.5-5       2016-10-15 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
##  modelr       0.1.1       2017-07-24 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  munsell      0.4.3       2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  nlme         3.1-131     2017-02-06 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  parallel     3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  pillar       1.0.99.9001 2018-01-16 Github (r-lib/pillar@9d96835)     
##  pkgconfig    2.0.1       2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  plyr         1.8.4       2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  psych        1.7.8       2017-09-09 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  purrr      * 0.2.4.9000  2017-12-05 Github (tidyverse/purrr@62b135a)  
##  R6           2.2.2       2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  rbenchmark * 1.0.0       2012-08-30 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
##  Rcpp         0.12.15     2018-01-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  readr      * 1.1.1       2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  readxl       1.0.0       2017-04-18 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  reshape2     1.4.2       2016-10-22 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  rlang        0.1.6       2017-12-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  rmarkdown    1.8         2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  rprojroot    1.3-2       2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  rvest        0.3.2       2016-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  scales       0.5.0.9000  2017-12-02 Github (hadley/scales@d767915)    
##  sf         * 0.6-1       2018-01-24 Github (r-spatial/sf@7ea67a5)     
##  stats      * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  stringi      1.1.6       2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  stringr    * 1.2.0       2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                    
##  tibble     * 1.4.1.9000  2018-01-18 Github (tidyverse/tibble@64fedbd) 
##  tidyr      * 0.7.2.9000  2018-01-13 Github (tidyverse/tidyr@74bd48f)  
##  tidyverse  * 1.2.1       2017-11-14 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  tools        3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  udunits2     0.13        2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
##  units        0.5-1       2018-01-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  utf8         1.1.3       2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
##  utils      * 3.4.0       2017-04-21 local                             
##  withr        2.1.1.9000  2018-01-13 Github (jimhester/withr@df18523)  
##  xml2         1.1.1       2017-01-24 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
##  yaml         2.1.14      2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can considerably speed-up this by simply dropping the unnecessary `map_lgl` call in the pipe:

```r
bm_sf_dplyr_large_fast <- benchmark({
  int_new <- nc_1e4 %>% mutate(INT = st_intersects_any(., nc_wtr))
}, columns = cols, replications = 1)
bm_sf_dplyr_large_fast

# bm_sf_dplyr_large_fast
# elapsed relative
# 1   0.829        1
```

The huge slow down depends from the fact that mapping over geometry rows is in this case detrimental, because you then do a looped one-to-multi polygon intersection.

Besides the overhead introduced by subsetting, I believe this is much slower than a straight-on multi-to-multi because you are probably mostly losing the **"spatial indexing"  capabilities** of `sf` objects, which considerably speed-up intersect operations (see http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/22/spatial-index.html). (Also note that I substituted `transmute' with`mutate` - also that was introducing some overhead).

HTH

Comment: Sounds like we have a general design principle: avoid row-wise operations if the step involves a binary logical predicates (like st_intersects, st_crosses, etc.) because you lose the spatial indexing efficiency boost. 

Does that seem correct to you? 

Would this apply for other spatial operations (e.g., st_buffer)?

Comment: That is also my understanding, though I can not really comment about sf "design principles" since I am not a developer. Maybe @Edzer Pebesma could chime in on this when/if he has time?