# Identifying observations that overlap in space and time

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame were each row is a unique observation.

Observations overlap in time if they are located within a specified temporal distance (e.g. 30 days) of one another.

Observations overlap in space if they are located within a specified spatial distance (e.g. 20 kilometers) of one another.

I am working with the collections of observations that overlap in both time and space. I want to make a column (overlaps) that contains vectors with the ids of the observations that overlap with an observation. I have tried the solution below, but the run time is too poor for the solution to be applicable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(geosphere)

spat_proximity <- function(x, y, z) {
  
  return(which(map_dbl(y, ~ distGeo(., x)) <= z))}


temp_proximity <- function(x, y, z) {
    
  return(which(map_dbl(y, ~ abs(x - .)) <= z))}


test %>%
  mutate(overlaps = map2(map(place, ~ spat_proximity(., place, 20000)),
                         map(time, ~ temp_proximity(., time, 30)),
                         ~ intersect(.x, .y)))
```

Ideas on how to speed things up would be much appreciated.

**Desired output**

```
structure(list(id = 1:42, time = structure(c(1478601762, 1475170279, 
1469770219, 1462441336, 1474739469, 1488216507, 1475203721, 1468705558, 
1481722718, 1485897197, 1488669576, 1501288618, 1510266595, 1516828588, 
1497048175, 1516546144, 1507576242, 1517654363, 1496070298, 1519765220, 
1507408104, 1532046710, 1542196446, 1534747170, 1533605231, 1521381844, 
1545389880, 1537988628, 1544304998, 1524842149, 1551051077, 1540822870, 
1579775599, 1580337175, 1551486497, 1554879837, 1568620434, 1568701543, 
1556387550, 1561253396, 1582925482, 1562166384), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), place = list(c(7.59729413351368, 52.6052275122351
), c(9.99728447956781, 53.43773657253), c(10.1114473929533, 53.1295890148866
), c(7.74115218835801, 53.555354690339), c(9.82895066827581, 
53.1009319396015), c(10.061107415855, 53.1908752763309), c(10.1134381934544, 
53.1450558612239), c(8.59001735546083, 53.1767797285482), c(6.43939168487555, 
52.5520931654252), c(8.38811111096636, 53.9043055557574), c(6.20061916537948, 
52.462037409576), c(8.66656282486832, 52.8269702466929), c(9.92127490588442, 
53.1240045666796), c(9.77810957468704, 53.1445777603789), c(10.0972382106036, 
53.1604265989175), c(10.0473952445094, 53.1698097395641), c(9.23773401919961, 
53.2120381900218), c(8.29524237837988, 52.822332696399), c(6.63690696797941, 
53.4436726627048), c(6.89839325296288, 53.947454203445), c(6.97064542834721, 
54.2487197094445), c(9.98865072631714, 53.4088944299342), c(9.94164401569524, 
53.1500576073959), c(9.64242996587752, 52.9285470044703), c(10.1026940185685, 
53.1635394335485), c(9.94874529044194, 53.2202512735354), c(8.8025526552284, 
53.2423093779114), c(7.93352467761445, 52.9129105531343), c(6.6418846001424, 
53.2459031608081), c(7.56102465003101, 53.5306444680171), c(7.36619114998468, 
53.748869508885), c(7.40993284414052, 54.5367797663042), c(9.90022663895919, 
53.3726361099083), c(9.41110555596208, 52.5001044709056), c(10.1151193231519, 
53.1539029361817), c(10.1064400828529, 53.1793449776572), c(9.94235711256256, 
53.2622041055899), c(9.44215997717822, 53.4799339987572), c(7.03832846889284, 
53.1986115213435), c(7.32755360272354, 53.416700338513), c(7.57828611098173, 
53.6107027769073), c(7.55411005022882, 54.1905803935834)), overlaps = list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, c(5L, 7L), 6L, c(5L, 7L), 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, c(14L, 16L), 15L, c(14L, 16L), 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
    21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
    33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(id = 1:42, time = structure(c(1478601762, 1475170279, 
1469770219, 1462441336, 1474739469, 1488216507, 1475203721, 1468705558, 
1481722718, 1485897197, 1488669576, 1501288618, 1510266595, 1516828588, 
1497048175, 1516546144, 1507576242, 1517654363, 1496070298, 1519765220, 
1507408104, 1532046710, 1542196446, 1534747170, 1533605231, 1521381844, 
1545389880, 1537988628, 1544304998, 1524842149, 1551051077, 1540822870, 
1579775599, 1580337175, 1551486497, 1554879837, 1568620434, 1568701543, 
1556387550, 1561253396, 1582925482, 1562166384), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), place = list(c(7.59729413351368, 52.6052275122351
), c(9.99728447956781, 53.43773657253), c(10.1114473929533, 53.1295890148866
), c(7.74115218835801, 53.555354690339), c(9.82895066827581, 
53.1009319396015), c(10.061107415855, 53.1908752763309), c(10.1134381934544, 
53.1450558612239), c(8.59001735546083, 53.1767797285482), c(6.43939168487555, 
52.5520931654252), c(8.38811111096636, 53.9043055557574), c(6.20061916537948, 
52.462037409576), c(8.66656282486832, 52.8269702466929), c(9.92127490588442, 
53.1240045666796), c(9.77810957468704, 53.1445777603789), c(10.0972382106036, 
53.1604265989175), c(10.0473952445094, 53.1698097395641), c(9.23773401919961, 
53.2120381900218), c(8.29524237837988, 52.822332696399), c(6.63690696797941, 
53.4436726627048), c(6.89839325296288, 53.947454203445), c(6.97064542834721, 
54.2487197094445), c(9.98865072631714, 53.4088944299342), c(9.94164401569524, 
53.1500576073959), c(9.64242996587752, 52.9285470044703), c(10.1026940185685, 
53.1635394335485), c(9.94874529044194, 53.2202512735354), c(8.8025526552284, 
53.2423093779114), c(7.93352467761445, 52.9129105531343), c(6.6418846001424, 
53.2459031608081), c(7.56102465003101, 53.5306444680171), c(7.36619114998468, 
53.748869508885), c(7.40993284414052, 54.5367797663042), c(9.90022663895919, 
53.3726361099083), c(9.41110555596208, 52.5001044709056), c(10.1151193231519, 
53.1539029361817), c(10.1064400828529, 53.1793449776572), c(9.94235711256256, 
53.2622041055899), c(9.44215997717822, 53.4799339987572), c(7.03832846889284, 
53.1986115213435), c(7.32755360272354, 53.416700338513), c(7.57828611098173, 
53.6107027769073), c(7.55411005022882, 54.1905803935834))), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: you can find a fast and memory-efficient way to calculate distances in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59915415/2761575)

Comment: Maybe relevant: [(Spatial) Efficient way of finding all points within X meters of a point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650274/spatial-efficient-way-of-finding-all-points-within-x-meters-of-a-point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you truly want speed you can write your own C++ code to calculate the distance [(because `geosphere` is quite slow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014364/5977215) and time comparisons

---

#### Example

Save this code in a file, for example `"~/Desktop/find_overlaps.cpp"`

you need to install `Rcpp` - `install.packages("Rcpp")`

```cpp
#include "Rcpp.h"
#include <math.h>

static const double earth = 6378137.0; // WSG-84 definition

// haversine formula taken from the geodist library
// - https://github.com/hypertidy/geodist
double distance_haversine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {

  double cosy1 = cos( y1 * M_PI / 180.0 );
  double cosy2 = cos( y2 * M_PI / 180.0 );

  double sxd = sin ((x2 - x1) * M_PI / 360.0);
  double syd = sin ((y2 - y1) * M_PI / 360.0);
  double d = syd * syd + cosy1 * cosy2 * sxd * sxd;
  d = 2.0 * earth * asin (sqrt (d));
  return (d);
}

// returns true if second date is within 30 days of the first
bool within_days( int first_date, int second_date ) {
  int days = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  int lower_bound = first_date - days;
  int upper_bound = first_date + days;

  return lower_bound <= second_date && second_date <= upper_bound;
}

bool within_distance( Rcpp::NumericVector start_place, Rcpp::NumericVector end_place, double distance_limit = 20000.0 ) {

  double x1 = start_place[0];
  double y1 = start_place[1];
  double x2 = end_place[0];
  double y2 = end_place[1];

  return distance_haversine(x1, y1, x2, y2) <= distance_limit;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP find_overlaps( Rcpp::NumericVector ids, Rcpp::IntegerVector dates, Rcpp::List place ) {

  R_xlen_t n = dates.length();
  R_xlen_t i, j;

  Rcpp::List res( n );

  R_xlen_t result_counter;
  for( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {

    Rcpp::IntegerVector overlaps( n ); // initialise vector to store results
    result_counter = 0;

    for( j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
      // ignore self-comparisons
      if( i != j ) {

        int first_date = dates[ i ];
        int second_date = dates[ j ];

        Rcpp::NumericVector first_place = place[ i ];
        Rcpp::NumericVector second_place = place[ j ];

        // check the place values exist
        if( first_place.length() != 2 || second_place.length() != 2 ) {
          continue;
        }

        if( within_days( first_date, second_date) && within_distance( first_place, second_place ) ) {
          overlaps[ result_counter ] = j;
          result_counter++;
        }
      }

      if( result_counter > 0 ) {
        Rcpp::IntegerVector id_idx = overlaps[ Rcpp::Range( 0, result_counter - 1 ) ];
        res[ i ] = ids[ id_idx ];
      }

    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Then source it in R

```r
library(Rcpp)

Rcpp::sourceCpp(file = "~/Desktop/find_overlaps.cpp")

res <- find_overlaps( df$id, df$time, df$place )

df$overlaps <- res

df
#    id                time               place overlaps
# 1   1 2016-11-08 10:42:42 7.597294, 52.605228     NULL
# 2   2 2016-09-29 17:31:19 9.997284, 53.437737     NULL
# 3   3 2016-07-29 05:30:19  10.11145, 53.12959     NULL
# 4   4 2016-05-05 09:42:16 7.741152, 53.555355     NULL
# 5   5 2016-09-24 17:51:09 9.828951, 53.100932        7
# 6   6 2017-02-27 17:28:27  10.06111, 53.19088     NULL
# 7   7 2016-09-30 02:48:41  10.11344, 53.14506        5
# 8   8 2016-07-16 21:45:58 8.590017, 53.176780     NULL
# 9   9 2016-12-14 13:38:38 6.439392, 52.552093     NULL
# 10 10 2017-01-31 21:13:17 8.388111, 53.904306     NULL
# 11 11 2017-03-04 23:19:36 6.200619, 52.462037     NULL
# 12 12 2017-07-29 00:36:58 8.666563, 52.826970     NULL
# 13 13 2017-11-09 22:29:55 9.921275, 53.124005     NULL
# 14 14 2018-01-24 21:16:28   9.77811, 53.14458       16
# 15 15 2017-06-09 22:42:55  10.09724, 53.16043     NULL
# 16 16 2018-01-21 14:49:04  10.04740, 53.16981       14
# 17 17 2017-10-09 19:10:42 9.237734, 53.212038     NULL
# 18 18 2018-02-03 10:39:23 8.295242, 52.822333     NULL
# 19 19 2017-05-29 15:04:58 6.636907, 53.443673     NULL
# 20 20 2018-02-27 21:00:20 6.898393, 53.947454     NULL
# ...
```

#### Notes

- I ran a quick benchmark and it ran on your example in microseconds
- I've purposefully ignored self-overlaps (hence the `NULL` values)

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution using `spatialrisk` and `dplyr`. The key functions in `spatialrisk` are written in C++ (Rcpp), and are therefore very fast.

`spatialrisk::points_in_circle()` calculates the observations within radius from a center point. Note that distances are calculated using the Haversine formula.

```
library(spatialrisk)
library(dplyr)

# Find rows within time period
overlap_time_fn <- function(df, days, time_ref){
  seconds <- days * 24 * 3600
  df %>%
    filter(time < time_ref + seconds, time > time_ref - seconds) 
}

# Define radius in meters
dist <- 20000

# Define number of days
days <- 30

df %>%
  mutate(lon = place[[1]][1]) %>% # add lon column
  mutate(lat = place[[1]][2]) %>% # add lat column
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(overlap_spat = toString(points_in_circle(., lon_center = lon,      
                                                     lat_center = lat, 
                                                     radius = dist)$id)) %>%
  mutate(overlap_time = toString(overlap_time_fn(., days = days, 
                                                    time_ref = time)$id))
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution with `data.table` :

- **reduce the number of matching pairs** in space and time using **non-equi joins**
- calculate distance and time differences **for the selected pairs only**
- keep the results corresponding exactly to the expected criteria
- group by `id`

On example dataset, performance comparison shows around `x20` improvement, see below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(geosphere)
library(data.table)


maxtime <- 30
maxdist <- 20000

setDT(test)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark( datatable = {# Calculate box around each point
test[,c('x','y','boxxmin','boxxmax','boxymin','boxymax','timemin','timemax'):=.(
        sapply(place,function(x) x[1]),
        sapply(place,function(x) x[2]),
        sapply(place,function(x) x[1] - maxdist),
        sapply(place,function(x) x[1] + maxdist),
        sapply(place,function(x) x[2] - maxdist),
        sapply(place,function(x) x[2] + maxdist),
        sapply(time,function(t) t - maxtime * 86400),
        sapply(time,function(t) t + maxtime * 86400))]


# Select near enough places
result <- test[test,.(place,i.id,i.time,i.place,i.x,i.y,id,x,y,time, place),on=.(x>=boxxmin, y>=boxymin, x <= boxxmax, y<= boxymax , time >= timemin, time <= timemax)]

# Calculate spatio-temporal distances
result[,c('dist','dt'):=.(distGeo(matrix(unlist(i.place),ncol=2,byrow=T),matrix(unlist(place),ncol=2,byrow=T)),
                         abs(as.numeric(difftime(i.time,time,unit = 'days')))) ]

# Calculate overlaps
overlaps <- result[dt < 30 & dist < 20000 ][,.(overlap = list(i.id)), by = .(id)]

test[overlaps,.(id,time,place,overlap),on=.(id=id)]
    id                time               place overlap
 1:  1 2016-11-08 10:42:42  7.597294,52.605228       1
 2:  2 2016-09-29 17:31:19  9.997284,53.437737       2
 3:  3 2016-07-29 05:30:19   10.11145,53.12959       3
 4:  4 2016-05-05 09:42:16  7.741152,53.555355       4
 5:  5 2016-09-24 17:51:09  9.828951,53.100932     5,7
 6:  7 2016-09-30 02:48:41   10.11344,53.14506     5,7
 7:  6 2017-02-27 17:28:27   10.06111,53.19088       6
 8:  8 2016-07-16 21:45:58  8.590017,53.176780       8
 9:  9 2016-12-14 13:38:38  6.439392,52.552093       9
10: 10 2017-01-31 21:13:17  8.388111,53.904306      10
11: 11 2017-03-04 23:19:36  6.200619,52.462037      11
12: 12 2017-07-29 00:36:58  8.666563,52.826970      12
13: 13 2017-11-09 22:29:55  9.921275,53.124005      13
14: 14 2018-01-24 21:16:28    9.77811,53.14458   14,16
15: 16 2018-01-21 14:49:04   10.04740,53.16981   14,16
16: 15 2017-06-09 22:42:55   10.09724,53.16043      15
17: 17 2017-10-09 19:10:42  9.237734,53.212038      17
...
```

Performance comparison :

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 datatable   9.0788  10.21605  11.75099  10.7112  11.7880  24.6698   100  a 
     purrr 176.7696 199.85610 209.79916 209.2215 218.3165 253.2139   100   b
```

Comment: @rjen, is the output as expected?

Comment: The output has the format that I am after. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try `lapply` function, most of the time it is more efficient and some times define functions with `~` is not a good idea. Try this:

```
p <- do.call(rbind,data$place)
t <- data$time

y <- data %>%
      mutate(overlaps = map2(lapply(place,function(x)which(distGeo(x,p2=p)<=20000)),
                             map(time,function(x)which(abs(as.numeric(difftime(x,t,units = "days")))<=30)),
                             intersect))
```

Comment: "most of the time it is more efficient" - I'm not sure I agree with this statement, as an `lapply` is still technically a loop (in R), and the `distGeo` is a big bottleneck in speed. Have you benchmarked your solution against the others?

Comment: Yes, I do.Mine is better. `map` has some small details that reduce its efficiency, however all that is compensated with other things. Check https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/

Comment: Here is another post will clarify my claim. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101045/why-use-purrrmap-instead-of-lapply